# OTRS Single Sign On (SSO) on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache, module, single-sign-on, otrs

I am attempting to install SSO on Linux with Apache, but I don't understand why a Linux system has an ntdomain, or even what an ntdomain is precisely.

http://wiki.otterhub.org/index.php?title=Implementing_Single_Sign_On_on_Linux_with_Apache#Installing_Modules

```
<Location /otrs>
  PerlAuthenHandler Apache2::AuthenNTLM
  AuthType ntlm,basic
  AuthName Basic
  require valid-user
  PerlAddVar ntdomain "DOMAIN dc bdc"
  PerlSetVar defaultdomain DOMAIN
  PerlSetVar splitdomainprefix 1
</Location>
```

and

```
$Self->{'Customer::AuthModule'} = 'Kernel::System::CustomerAuth::HTTPBasicAuth';
$Self->{CustomerPanelLoginURL} = 'http://otrs-server/otrs/no_sso_login_possible.html';
$Self->{CustomerPanelLogoutURL} = 'http://otrs-server/otrs/logout.html';
```

Why is there an ntdomain? I don't know what that is in a Linux context. I don't know how to do it from the documentation.

besides that, it seems different than the documentation on the github site. Is there a plain English explanation, or am I just stupid or something?

http://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/3.1/en/html/auth-backends.html#customer-auth-backend-httpbasic

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to do...

The example from the Otterhub-Wiki focuses on providing SSO for Windows-Clients in a Windows-Domain using NTLM: User log onto their workstations with their domain-credentials and those get passed to OTRS/Apache.

The example from the Admin-Manual (using Kernel::System::CustomerAuth::HTTPBasicAuth) is a more generic approach - but technically speaking almost the same as the NTLM-stuff.

The basic idea here is, that you have done some kind of authentication for your user somewhere else and then have set the `Authorization`-header - just like the HTTP-Basic-Auth would do.

OTRS is then using the username provided by the `Authorization`-header to query the local user-Database.

tl;dr: In the first example, you set the `Authorization`-header by taking the relevant information from NTLM, in the second example you have to find your way around and set an appropriate header yourself.